# library to implement comment in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, comments

Is there any good library to implement facebook like comments and +1 system for code igniter. I googled it but couldnt manage to find one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use http://disqus.com that is a great tool for comments

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Facebook helper function](http://www.thephpx.com/2010/06/20/codeigniter-facebook-social-plugin-like-button-helper/) for CodeIgniter. Since the Google +1 code also includes JavaScript, it might need two helper functions so you can place them in the appropriate areas. Using the same principle as the Facebook helper function though, you should be able to create your own for Google +1.